# Looping and Updating a Variable instead of Overwriting it , React Native

Tags: reactjs, react-native, expo

I am a beginner with React Native. I have a loop in my program that goes through some results from an API and for each result (postcode), it drops a pin on a map with the corresponding coordinates.

```
const showPostcode = async() => {

  {parkingPostcode && parkingPostcode.map((val, index) => {

    console.log(val.postcode);
    searchMultipleSpaces(val.postcode)
    console.log("=============")

    key={index}

  })}

}
```

The function above is the loop that goes through the results gathered from the API.

As you can see, it calls another function `searchMultipleSpaces(val.postcode)`. 
Here is the function:

```
const searchMultipleSpaces = async(postcodee) => {
  const response = await camdenParking.get("", {

    params:{
      postcode: postcodee
    }

  })

  setparkingSpaces(response.data)   
}
```

As you can see, in the second function we set `setparkingSpaces` with whatever the API returns. The issue is that for each different iteration the data will be overwritten. So in the end the data will only contain the results from the last iteration. What should I do so that every result from all the iterations is saved in there without being overwritten?

This is where I use parkingSpaces :

```
                {parkingSpaces.map((val, index) => {
                return (<MapView.Marker
                        coordinate={{
                        latitude: parseFloat(val.latitude),
                        longitude:parseFloat(val.longitude)
                        }}
                        key={index}
```

Comment: what you do in setparkingSpaces function

Comment: const [parkingSpaces,setparkingSpaces] = useState([]), It's just a state

Comment: so what you want to do is to store the array of "response.data"  in setparkingSpaces

Comment: yes indeed, however , i'm searching through multiple postcodes at once and values get overwritten in setParkingSpaces() as it will only keep the last postcode's response.data since the rest get overwritten

Answer (score 0):

what is suggest you that you convert your ***searchMultipleSpaces*** function into the promise and call all that at once like below

> What I change is that instead of returning whole response I make the new promise in it and then resolve the data element of response

```
const searchMultipleSpaces = async(postcodee) => {
  return new Promise((resolve,reject)=>{
     camdenParking.get("", {
       params:{
         postcode: postcodee
       }
      }).then(res=>resolve(res.data)).catch(err=>reject(err))
  }) 
}
```

and then call the ***searchMultipleSpaces***  with [Promise.all()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all)

like below

```
const showPostcode = async() => {
   let allPromise = [];
  {parkingPostcode && parkingPostcode.map((val, index) => {

     console.log(val.postcode);
     allPromise.push(searchMultipleSpaces(val.postcode))
     console.log("=============")

     key={index}

   })}

   const data = await Promise.all(allPromise);

  //here you get all the response at once and then send it to setparkingSpaces

   setparkingSpaces(data)   

}
```

Comment: Thanks, however, this raises another error. When I try to use the data it says invariant violation. I will update my post so you can see where I want to use the parkingSpaces

Comment: so when i search through the API i one need the data object, not the whole array. That's why I had response2.data. How can i only choose the data from the api reply?

Comment: ok so basically you don't need whole response you just need the data object which comes in response

Comment: Hi, I am getting the same error. I literally have no clue what to try next

Comment: sure, how do i share it ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/209071/discussion-between-cristian9804-and-ali-asgher-badshah).

Answer (score 0):

You should append the new data to the state instead of overwriting it, like so:

`setparkingSpaces(prevSpaces => [...prevSpaces, ...response.data])`